# What could cause huge graphical characters to appear in Gnome Terminal?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, unicode

I first found this when using `pipenv` under Ubuntu 18.04, none of my workmates seem to have this issue. Their characters are about the same height as a normal character and twice the width.

When *I* run it, I see rather large characters for the graphical aspect, such as with `pipenv sync` but it can be done by simply echoing the UTF-8 sequence (that's an `echo -e '\xf0\x9f\x90\x8b'` behind the whale<sup>(a)</sup>):

[image]

I cannot find *anything* in the `gnome-terminal` preferences (or the `dconf-editor`) which would indicate some characters would scale some seven times the size (it appears to take up seven lines and about fourteen column positions which matches the double-width behaviour seen by my workmates).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Which is supposed to be the *spouting* whale so the font may be badly designed anyway, but that's an issue quite separate from the size.

Comment: I dont know the answer but maybe gnome tweak can help you, install it with `sudo apt install gnome-tweak`

Comment: `gnome-tweaks` with an `s` by the looks of it but I found nothing in there to help. Thanks anyway, @yang.